# Как заставить QDialog принять размер своего содержимого?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть QDialog в котором есть QTableWidget (и всё). Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы размер окна (всего виджета) подстраивался под содержимое таблицы? Т.е. условно, если у меня всего 2 строки в таблице, чтобы он был в высоту ровно таким, чтобы эти 2 строки было видно. Благодарю!

Comment: По умолчанию такого нет, да и зачем  так делать?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ну я изучаю возможности и захотелось сделать так :) Ответ ниже в принципе решил эту проблему, но лишил возможности изменять размер окна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить QLayout диалога и задать `setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)`
или в designer в свойствах диалога в секции Layout задать для `layoutSizeConstraint` значение `SetFixedSize`

Comment: Принимаю Ваш ответ, спасибо. Это действительно помогло, но лишило возможности в дальнейшем изменять размер окна вручную. (Растягивать и сжимать)